# How can I start and stop a Timer using the same Button in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to programming, and I have this issue, which sounds pretty simple to me, but I'm too dumb to figure it out.

So... I want to make a `Timer` on my window form, that starts with a `Button`, and then the same `Button` stops it. and have a `Label` onscreen that just shows how many ticks the `Timer` has been going.

```cs
private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timer1.Enabled)
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    if (!timer1.Enabled)
        timer1.Enabled = true;
}
int c = 0;

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c++;
    lblTimer.Text = c.ToString();
}
```

The first button click works, it starts off the `Timer`, and the `Label` shows the counter, but I think it goes in an endless loop that prevents from the button being pressed again, because I can't stop the `Timer`? Can someone enlighten me on what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question, but your code in the `BtnStart_Click` method can be replaced with `timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;`. No `if`s needed.

Comment: quick patch: `if (timer1.Enabled) ... else if (!timer1.Enabled) ...` - please, note `else`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko actually `else` on its own should be enough (if it goes through the `else` branch, it already means that `timer1` is not enabled)

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens when you click your `Button` to stop the `Timer`:

```cs
// If the timer is enabled, it will disable it.
if (timer1.Enabled) {
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    // Timer is now disabled. That's good, that's what you want.
}

// At this point, the timer is disabled, so the next test will re-enable it!
if (!timer1.Enabled) {
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    // The Timer just go re-enabled :/
}
```

Fix this using an `else` statement:

```cs
if (timer1.Enabled)
    timer1.Enabled = false;
else
    timer1.Enabled = true;
```

so that only one of the two blocks runs.

Comment: This. What OP needs is to understand that with no `else`, the first `if` is pointless, because then the second `if` will revert the boolean value back.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can use following code example for above your scenario.

```
private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //when you click the button then the timer reacts as opposite value
    timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled
}
```

For the example, if timer is enabled then it will disable the timer when you click the button (BtnStart)

timer1 tick event-

```
int c = 0;
private void timer1_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    c++;
    label1.Text = c.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
```

Comment: While this is a common and good way to toggle a boolean, a bit of explanation aside from your line of code wouldn't hurt

Answer (score 0):

you can use this timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled; in your function of click button , when you click the timer have the opposite of the status

```
private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

you start the timer and in the next line you disable it again.

for example:

```
private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //when you click the button the value will be to opposite wich it was
    timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled
}
```

Comment: 1) it's C#, not C++, 2) There is no place to assume timer is not already a property yet. 3) if timer is not enabled it will not receive the Tick Event. So your while loop is first useless, and second endless. It will spin with a million increments per second.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I know ist c#, c is the Name from the int and the ++ is an increment. since you were corrct with the loop I overdid my answer.